# XSLT and XML combinations program

Tags: xml, xslt

I need solution for this problem can you please help on this.

```css
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<root>
    <row>
        <Currency>AED</Currency>
    </row>
    <row>
        <Currency>ARS</Currency>
    </row>
    <row>
        <Currency>AUD</Currency>
    </row>
</root>
```

**Expected Output**

```
<root>
    <row>
        <From_Currency>AED</From_Currency>
        <To_Currency>AED</To_Currency>
    </row>
    <row>
        <From_Currency>AED</From_Currency>
        <To_Currency>ARS</To_Currency>
    </row>
    <row>
        <From_Currency>AED</From_Currency>
        <To_Currency>AUD</To_Currency>
    </row>
    <row>
        <From_Currency>ARS</From_Currency>
        <To_Currency>AED</To_Currency>
    </row>
    <row>
        <From_Currency>ARS</From_Currency>
        <To_Currency>ARS</To_Currency>
    </row>
    <row>
        <From_Currency>ARS</From_Currency>
        <To_Currency>AUD</To_Currency>
    </row>
    <row>
        <From_Currency>AUD</From_Currency>
        <To_Currency>AED</To_Currency>
    </row>
    <row>
        <From_Currency>AUD</From_Currency>
        <To_Currency>ARS</To_Currency>
    </row>
    <row>
        <From_Currency>AUD</From_Currency>
        <To_Currency>AUD</To_Currency>
    </row>

</root>
```

Comment: I need out put like this --

Comment: I need Output XML like   (EX: 123 -> 11,12,13,21,22,23,31,32,33)
by using XSLT

Comment: You need to supply more information. You say you need a solution for "this problem" but you haven't specified what "this problem" is.

Comment: My question in "Question column that is my input file"

Comment: My question in "Question column that is my input file"            I need out put XML by using XSLT is in "Answer coumn"

Comment: Please edit your question and place the expected output there (and delete the "answer" you posted).

Comment: Hi @michael.hor257k it is not allowing me to place question(input) and answer in same space that is why I have placed in answer slot which I need out put, sorry for inconvenience.... :)

Comment: Hey bro @michael.hor257k thank you so much your code is working fine.. :)

Answer (score 1):

Apparently you want to enumerate all possible [permutations (with repetition)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#Permutations_with_repetition) of the given set. This can be accomplished as follows:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each select="row">
            <xsl:variable name="from" select="Currency"/>
            <xsl:for-each select="../row">
                <row>
                    <From_Currency>
                        <xsl:value-of select="$from" />
                    </From_Currency>
                    <To_Currency>
                        <xsl:value-of select="Currency" />
                    </To_Currency>
                </row>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```